# How to update firebase without changing syntax

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native

I have no idea how to do this, but unfortunately the project ive been working on is running off of firebase 7.14.0, as a newer developer I have found this to be very tough to work with because there is no documentation. Is there anyway I can move to firebase 9 without having to change all of the syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use compatibility version however have little to no size or performance advantages over their version 8 counterparts.

```
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app"
import "firebae/compat/auth"
// import "firebase/compat/[SERVICE_NAME]"
```

Also as mentioned in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade),

> The compat libraries are a temporary solution that will be removed completely in a future major SDK version (such as version 10 or version 11). Your ultimate goal is to remove compat code and keep only version 9 modular-style code in your app.

Comment: So basically, all the old firebase 7 code will work with my new firebase 9 code in the same file?

Comment: @Charlie yes, you can keep using existing code with compat version so just need to change the imports as in the answer above. But do note that you should start migrating your code new syntax as these will be removed eventually.

Comment: @Charlie It is the temporary workaround from firebase, and it will be permanently removed in version 10 or 11. check the docs https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade